# Header banner images missing in IE?

Tags: php, image, internet-explorer, header

my header banner images displays fine in Firefox but not in IE. I usually just have a .Jpeg image but at Christmas time i have an animated .gif neither seem to display in IE. could someone please check this out for me?

http://www.clarksonsedinburgh.co.uk/

Many thanks,

Patrick

Comment: which version of IE you are using?

Comment: @Usman doesnt matter, I testd on 7, 8 and 9. Banner is not there on either one.

Comment: PS: Have you tried setting the height parameter?

Comment: And one more thing, why are you using `display: inline;` ?

Comment: hi you can try with my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code

```
<img width="966" height="100%" alt="Clarksons of Edinburgh" src="/imgs/bg/clarksons Christmas.gif">
```

Comment: good point about the inline; that was still there from the last people who maintained my site and i must have overlooked this. i have tried your code but still no luck!

Comment: Its working for me... please change 100% give any size like 300px like that

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="/imgs/bg/clarksons Christmas.gif" width="966" height="" alt="Clarksons of Edinburgh" />
```

Maybe it doesnt like height=""

Comment: hi guys that's it sorted it was the height issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your image height is not specified and IE consider it as having the height=1

Set the height attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML1512: Unmatched end tag. 
www.clarksonsedinburgh.co.uk, line 39 character 1
HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document. 
www.clarksonsedinburgh.co.uk, line 40 character 1
HTML1508: Unmatched end tag. 
www.clarksonsedinburgh.co.uk, line 82 character 286
```

This is what IE alerts me

Comment: thanks for all your help guys and i shall check those alerts out. these are probably when i took over the site and changed the coding a bit i may have left tags in but filtering through slowly